# fopen() returns NULL although file exists

Tags: c, file, sockets, tcp, tcpserver

TCP client (that I'm also programming) is sending a filename through a TCP socket and TCP server should return the whole file. The problem is `fopen()` in the code below is constantly returning `NULL` although the file exists (I'm calling the `./TCP_server` from the directory where the file is located).

```
char filename[MAX_FILENAME];

bzero(filename, MAX_FILENAME);
while (1) {
    int newSock;

    if ((newSock = accept(sock, res->ai_addr, &res->ai_addrlen)) == -1) {
        errx(2, "Error while accepting.");
    }

    char offset[4];

    if (readn(newSock, &offset, 4) == -1) {
        errx(2, "%s", "Error while reading offset.");
    }

    char c[1];
    int i = 0;

    while (c[0] != '\0') {
        if (i != 0)
            strncat(filename, c, 1);
        i++;
        if (readn(newSock, c, 1) == -1) {
            errx(2, "%s", strerror(errno));
        }

    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");

    char status;
    char message[256];

    if (fp == NULL) {
        if (errno == ENOENT) {
            status = 1;
            strcpy(message, "File doesn't exist.");
        }
        else if (errno == EACCES) {
            status = 2;
            strcpy(message, "No read permission.");
        }
        else {
            status = 3;
            strcpy(message, "Unknown error.");
        }
        if (writen(newSock, &status, 1) == -1) {
            errx(2, "Error while writing 1 byte.");
        }
        if (writen(newSock, message, strlen(message)) == -1) {
            errx(2, "Error while sending message.");
        }
    }
}
```

Printing the filename before or after `fopen()` shows the correct string but `fopen()` still returns `NULL`. `perror()` prints `No such file or directory`.

Comment: The _second_ time through the outer `while` loop will have leftover data in `filename` from the previous iteration. Move the `bzero(filename, MAX_FILENAME);` under the `while` so the `strncat` works correctly.

Comment: In the while loop where you check `c[0]` it has not been initialised the first time round. Looks like you’d be better  to use a different type of loop.